# перевод Double значения времени( сек) в unix формат

Tags: java, время, datetime, timestamp, таймер

Например, вот такая дата со временем: **2017.01.12 22:44:0.9999**

То конвертируем это все в секунды: **3600 * 22 + 60 * 44 + 0.9999**

И вот секунды представлены в **Float** значении.

И как мне это перевести в **unix**?

Comment: дата вам приходит извне?

Comment: Узнайте сколько секунд первого января, 1970, вычтите

Comment: это через парсинг получаю такую дату. секунды там как я понял в миллисекундах уже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Unix time' -- это не вещественное, а целое число. Самый естественный способ получить из вещественного значения целое - это округлить его. Можно, конечно, не округлять, а отбрасывать дробную часть, но при этом будет получаться время, отстающее от действительного в среднем на полсекунды. Округление:

```
 double doubleTime =  3600 * 22 + 60 * 44 + 0.9999;
 long unixTime = Math.round(doubleTime);
```

Другой вопрос, что в Java намного чаще употребляется время в миллисекундах, чем в секундах -- есть множество классов и методов для работы со временем в таком виде, например для преобразования такого времени в строку в нужном формате. Если вы предпочтете использовать такое представление времени, то это можно делать вот так:

```
 double doubleTimeMs =  (3600 * 22 + 60 * 44 + 0.9999) * 1000; // в миллисекундах
 long javaTime = Math.round(doubleTimeMs); 
 String thatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(javaTime);
 System.out.println("That time was " + thatTime);
 long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
 System.out.println("Now is        " 
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(now);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unix timestamp исчисляется с точностью до секунд(миллисекунд) и отсчитывается с полуночи 1 января 1970 года.

Т.е. для 2017.01.12 22:44:0.9999 (считаем, что это Гринвич, чтобы временными зонами не заморачиваться), будет так

Составляющая от годов: (2017 - 1970) * 31536000 = 1482192000 (необходима поправка на високосные года)

Месяц тут не сыграет (и слава богу)

Составляющая от дней: 12 * 86400 = 1036800

Составляющая от часов и минут: 22 * 3600 + 44 * 60 = 81840

Итого: 1484174640 секунд (Это без учета високосных лет и прочих корректировок)

Теперь с секундами. Есть два пути:

1) Если вам нужна временная метка в секундах, то нецелое значение можно округлить `Math.round()` (или отбросить, например `Math.floor()`)

2) Использовать таймштамп в миллисекундах. Тогда как-то так:

`Long timestamp = 1484174640 * 1000 + Math.round(0.9999 * 1000);`

Но в целом, это очередное изобретение велосипеда. Для Java есть большое количество библиотек(включая стандартную), которые позволяют корректно работать с датами практически в любых форматах.